# Using a custom ListView with bitmap images not resources

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an app that downloads Base64 encoded images from an API in the form of JSON, these images are then parsed and decoded and stored in a Bitmap[]. I want to display these in a ListView with text but most of the examples I have seen use resources already stored in the app. Is there any way to create what it need?

Comment: use aquery for that..https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading

Comment: myImageView.setImageBitmap(mynewBitmapfromBase64);

Comment: it will do much work for you,,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code you found in the example, but instead of calling imageView.setImageResource you can call something like that:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(myImageBase64,Base64.NO_WRAP);
InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```